# Archive source folder contents not the folder in azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

i am using azure-pipelines to create a build of my react app and then to deploy it to azure app-service now when i build the app all the required contents go it "/build" folder which then i archive and publish to build artifacts with the corresponding tasks. but the issue is in the archive the structure is "/build/{required files}" but i need the structure as "/{required files}" is there any way to achieve it on azure-pipelines.

i have already looked in azure documentation there they show a variable named "includeRootFolder" but even in the link it does not have a description and in the Archive task i am not able to see any option which will set this variable to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option "Prepend root folder name to archive paths" on the task "Archive files" and is enabled per default which causes the behaviour you encounter. Just uncheck this option and this should fix your structure